# Mesh network wired nodes: series or parallel connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, imesh

I'm considering setting up a 3 node mesh router: one parent node connected directly to the modem and 2 wired child nodes.

I was planning to connect a LAN port of the parent node to the switch in the basement that feeds all Ethernet jacks in the house. I then would connect the child node's WAN ports to Ethernet jacks in the rooms they will be in. In that case both child nodes would be connected in parallel to the parent node.

To my surprise I found a hookup diagram from the Linksys websites. https://www.linksys.com/support-article?articleNum=217442 which states you should connect them in series. This is non-intuitive to me since it creates more network hops than needed. Also: my home wiring would not support this and I have no interest in running new wires.

[image]

Questions:

1. Will parallel wiring work?
2. If both wiring options are feasible which one is better and why?

**EDIT** If the exact model matters, lets assume https://www.linksys.com/mx4200---tri-band-ax4200-mesh-wifi-6-router/MX4200.html

Comment: Are you using Linksys products, specifically? Not all "mesh nodes" are identical.

Comment: I was planning to but haven't bought yet. How would I able  to determine which "mesh nodes" support parallel wiring. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the article
[How to add a wired child node to the mesh system using the Linksys app](https://www.linksys.com/support-article?articleNum=217442)
says you *should* connect nodes in series.
It just tells how you *can* do that, if you need to, via the Linksys app.

There are no miracles, and additional hops in the network will add
latency. The described Ethernet LAN structure should have good
performance in both serial and parallel configurations for your case
of a network of only three nodes. A star topology is
usually the most efficient because it minimizes the number of hops.